# Proc export to update an existing excel sheet in SAS?

Tags: excel, sas, proc

I am trying to update (keep adding rows) an existing excel file (if it is somehow possible) but the data keeps replacing or overwriting. I want the Claims tab to keep updating when the sas is ran. Adding "REPLACE" would overwrite the data as well. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
proc export
data=hdat.revclaimsmaster 
outfile="\TEST.xlsx"
dbms=excel;
SHEET="Claims";
run;

proc export
data=hdat.nonrevclaimsmaster  
outfile="\TEST.xlsx"
dbms=excel;
SHEET="Claims";
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the "replace" option:

```
dbms = excel replace;
```

Comment: That would just overwrite the existing data. I need it to add

Comment: Add in what way? Are you trying to add rows to a dataset or something? If so, why not just compile the dataset in SAS before exporting as opposed to exporting a bunch of times

Comment: That's correct, I want to keep adding rows to an existing excel sheet. Could you help me with an example of compiling? Im not too familiar with it. Thanks for your help

Comment: So presumably you have one SAS dataset that you want to export and a second SAS dataset that you want to export and have it appear under the first one. Assuming the datasets have the same columns, you can do something like -- data stack; set dataset1 dataset2; run; -- and then output the stacked dataset instead of the two individual datasets. This will run much faster and, in your case, actually work. If you have specific questions, it would help if you edited your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SAS datasets are local and you are using Windows, you can use a nifty SAS macro program call **exportToXL**.  Just google for it and it comes with instructions on how to set it up.  Once you get the hang of it, it is as easy as 123.

The only caveats are,
1.  You need to have PC SAS on your PC to use this program.
2.  The version is quite old and the developer did not update to handle new Excel workbooks file format i.e. it use .xls and not .xlsx.  That said and if you are good with SAS programming, you can modify the program to handle .xlsx like I did.

HTH,
Lobbie

Comment: This isn't a good answer as it stands.  If you want to make it a good answer, provide some more detail about how `%exportToXL` works.  Otherwise, this is just a tool/library suggestion and isn't really what we're looking for on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Joe - Thank you and will keep this in mind next time.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  None of them are objectively better, though, than the answer provided by Superfluous - appending to the dataset in SAS then re-exporting.

1. Use [DDE](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p011-26.pdf) to perform your update.  Advantage: very easy to update data.  Disadvantage: barely if at all supported any longer, and requires excel to run on the same PC as SAS.
2. Use a connection to Excel (`connect to excel`).  Advantage: connecting lets you perform SQL statements, including inserts, in place.  Disadvantage: has to conform to a reasonable SAS data structure, can't do formatting, can't do random inserts easily. (h/t Roger DeAngelis @ SAS-L for pointing this one out)
3. Use the SAS Add-In to Microsoft Excel.  Advantage: lets you control things from Excel more readily, much more powerful formatting options as a result.  Disadvantage: separate product has to be licensed, and is driven from Excel not SAS (though runs SAS code on a server, in stored procedures).
4. Connect to SAS's OLEDB provider from Excel. Similar to 3, really, with a bit less control and a different (perhaps cheaper) product license.
5. Import your data, modify it, then re-export using REPLACE.  Advantage: easy to do in SAS, control over data in SAS.  Disadvantage: has to conform to SAS data structure, has to write all rows out again (so could be slow).  This is roughly Superfluous's suggestion.